# GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS in App Engine Flex

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml, app-engine-flexible

I'm using the ML engine API from App Engine Flex (Python 2.7). The project has been set up by others and I've been told to export this variable when running the code on my machine

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="$PWD/f217XXXXX.json"
```

I checked the Cloud Console and this corresponds to a key of the App Engine default service account.

When I deployed the app, I got this error:
[image: stacktrace 1][image: stacktrace 2][image: stacktrace 3]

Any idea where it comes from ? Is it because it does not use the right credentials when deployed ?

FYI, this is how we retrieve the credentials in the code:

```
CREDENTIALS = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
ml_client = discovery.build('ml', 'v1', credentials=CREDENTIALS)
```

Comment: Hi! When you say "running the code on my machine", what are you referring to? Are you running the code in a local machine?

Comment: @GuillermoCacheda yes

Comment: I'm leaning to an issue with the credentials, they might not be being properly retrieved. When using `JSON` files for authenticating in the code, is recommended to [explicitly point to the file in code](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#passing_the_path_to_the_service_account_key_in_code). Try updating the implementation and see if it fixes the deployment.